# Delphi link to windows dll statically or dynamically

Tags: windows, delphi, dll, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am aware that implicitly linking to libraries at load time can lead to performance increases and as such I was wondering if it was good practice to link in this way at compile time thus increasing executable size (admittedly this is only marginal) compared to linking explicitly at runtime. My question is when linking against Microsoft Windows dll files located in System32, is it 'better' to link at load time as you can be mostly certain that the libraries will be present or follow the explicit approach?

Language used is Delphi (pascal) and the library in question is the WTsAPI32.dll - Terminal Services.

**EDIT:** As pointed out - my choice of language was incorrect and has been amended. Also, due to having only really every extensively linked to libraries in Unix, my comments about executable size can be omitted, I believed at the time I WAS in fact referring to static linking which bundles the library code into the executable and I now realise this is impossible when using dll files (DUH!). Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two forms of DLL linking are perhaps better named implicit and explicit. Implicit linking is what you refer to as static linking. And explicit linking is what you refer to as runtime linking

For implicit linking the linker writes entries into the import table of the executable file. This import table is metadata that is used by the loader to resolve DLL imports at module load time. A stub function is included for each implicit import that is only a few bytes in size. The executable size implications of implicit linking are negligible.

With explicit linking the imported function's address is resolved by a call to GetProcAddress. This call is made when the programmer chooses. If the DLL or the function cannot be resolved, the programmer can code fall back behaviour. There are size implications to explicit linking that I estimate to be similar to implicit linking. If the function address is evaluated once and remembered between calls then the performance characteristics are similar to implicit linking.

My advice is as follows:

1. Prefer implicit linking. It is more convenient to code.
2. If the DLL may not be present, use explicit linking.
3. If the DLL must be loaded using a full path, use explicit linking.
4. If you want to unload the DLL during program execution, use explicit linking.

You specifically mention Windows DLLs. You can safely assume that they will be present. Don't try to code to allow your program to run in case user32.dll is missing. Some functions may not be present in older versions of Windows. If you support those older versions you'll need to use explicit linking and provide a fallback. Decide which version you support and use MSDN to be sure that a function is available on your minimum supported platform.

Comment: AFAIR my debugging sessions those stubs are only consisting of JMP FAR insturction. So it is either single extra byte (JMP FAR DIRECT - $E9 opcode) or 5 bytes (JMP FAR indIRECT + address of the pointer var). But AFAIR that was the former option. So... well... they are stubs, but those stubs only takes one extra byte.  And that would me much less than the prologue to call `GetProcAddress` and check for errors. Then add there finding and choosing the certain version of DLL given by name and runtime binding grows yet even larger in code.

Comment: @Arioch There's also the import table, but size implications are similar, like I said.

Comment: I don't think they are similar. Storing IDs as utf-16 consts rather than 8-bit ANSI import table alone would overweight those 4-bytes pointer. And then there usually would be custom code for every single procedure that outweights this yet more. I don't believe in a practical application where explicit linking would result in smaller binary than OS-provided one.

Comment: @Arioch Define similar. Hard to argue over such an imprecise term. My explicit linking is table based using a utility class. Store names as AnsiString and it's close. In the context of all the rest of the code in a program, either way has negligible impact. What's more, import table can be paged out after use. Explicit linking cannot. All sorts of differences, none of them add up to much.

Comment: Thank you, with regard to library management I am far more comfortable in a Unix based environment and even then my library knowledge is fairly limited. Your answer clarified the various subtleties that I was unsure of. Much appreciated and thanks for decoding my improper use of static/dynamic, I'll have a bit more to read up on now.

Answer (score 3):

If your only two options are **static linking** and **run-time dynamic linking**, then the latter is the best choice for linking with Windows DLLs because it's your *only* choice. You cannot link statically to a DLL because DLLs are exclusively for dynamic linking; that's what the *D* stands for. Microsoft does not provide static libraries for the OS modules, so you cannot link to them statically.

But those typically *aren't* your only two options. There's a third, namely **load-time dynamic linking**.

In Delphi, you use load-time dynamic linking by marking a function declaration `external` and specifying the name of the DLL where the function resides. If you use the function, then an entry is created in your module's *import table*, and when the OS loads your module, it reads the table, loads the referenced DLL, looks up the address of the function, and stores the address in your program's memory image so that your program can call it directly.

You use run-time dyanmic linking by declaring a function *pointer*, and then using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to look up the function's address prior to calling it. In newer Delphi versions, you can also declare a function in the same style that load-time dynamic linking uses, but then mark it with `delay`. In that case, the Delphi run-time library will call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` on your behalf the first time you call the function.

The size differences are negligible. Run-time dynamic linking requires your program to contain code to load and link to libraries, but load-time dynamic linking stores more function references in the import table.

Run-time dynamic linking offers more flexibility in the face of uncertain DLL availability. With load-time dynamic linking, if a DLL is missing, or if it doesn't have *all* the functions mentioned in your import table, then the OS will fail to load your program — none of your code will run. With run-time dynamic linking, however, you have the opportunity to recover from the problem. You can disable certain parts of your program that the missing DLL depends on, or you can search for DLLs in non-standard places, or you can provide alternative implementations of missing functions.

If the functions you're calling are *integral* to your program's ability to operate, and there's ample reason to expect the functions to be present wherever your program is installed, then you should choose to link at load time. It allows you to write simpler code. You can be confident that you'll have the required functions if they are available on a certain version of windows that you check for in your installer, or if they're provided by DLLs that you distribute with your program.

On the other hand, if the functions you're calling are *optional*, then you should prefer to link at run time. Use that for loading plug-ins, or for taking advantage of advanced OS features while maintaining backward compatibility. (For example, you might want to take advantage of Windows Vista theme support when it's present, but still allow your program to run on Windows XP.)

Comment: This seems a little pedantic to me. Clearly the question asker says static and means implicit, says runtime and means explicit.

Comment: I'm not so sure, @David. Tjenks talks about increased EXE size, and static linking the only kind that has any significant effect in that regard.

Comment: It's common for people to use the term static in place of implicit or load time for dll linking. And hence the confusion.  It doesn't help that MS can't make their mind up on the terminology. Implicit/explicit or load-time/run-time.

Comment: @David, I think Tjenks heard that (real) static linking leads to larger binaries, and also heard load-time or implicit dynamic linking *referred to* as static linking, and erroneously joined the two concepts. I don't see how Microsoft's terminology causes anyone to think that any form of dynamic linking should actually be called *static*. It seems to me that people neglect to consider that there could be different *degrees* of dynamism. They know that run-time linking is *more dynamic* than load-time linking, and I suppose they conclude, "If it's not as dynamic, then it must be static."

Comment: All I meant is that it would be easier for everyone if there was a single name for each of these things! It's frustrating that Windows team uses one name and VS team another.

Comment: And i ended terming that as "early binding" and "late binding" because 1) ain't this binding too? and 2) in my perception "early" and "late" neatly convey that relativity that there is always something yet-even-earlier or later-than-late ;-)

Comment: Sigh - it seems my erroneous choice of language has caused some confusion. I am indeed talking about the differences between load-time and runtime. In my fairly tired state for some reason did not realise you could not statically link against a dynamic link library (believe it or not I did know the acronym) Give me .a/.so files any day - I'm fairly sure I understand their use. Thank you all for your help, the responses have been most educational in the ins and outs of library usage in Windows.

Comment: There is a distinction between binding and linking, @Arioch. Binding is for identifiers in your source code, whereas linking is for names in your compiled code. When you declare a DLL function, the identifier you assign to it is *bound* at compile time to a function to be imported later. That *identifier* will never refer to anything else in the program. Virtual functions are a form a dynamic binding. COM's IDispatch provides another. When IDispatch fails to recognize what function you're calling, that's a binding error, not a linking error.

Comment: @RobKennedy interesting idea, but it seems not thought through. In COM dual interfaces - like that `TExcelApplications` - there are dispid's - numerical offsets in VMTs AFAIU. Not textual "names" from sources. And when i call `TExcelApplication.Connect` there are no more sources and no more names - there are just numerical IDs. So then why is it called early binding if there is no more sources and names when it happening ? or should it be called linking then ?

Comment: We use *names* in our source code. Names have to be associated — bound — to something before they can be used. With late binding, we pass a name to an object's `GetIDsOfNames` method to discover the method's dispid. We then pass that ID to `Invoke` to have the object run the requested method's code. A dispid isn't a VMT offset (unless that's how the object chose to implement `Invoke`; that's an implementation detail). With early binding, a `dispinterface` maps names to IDs, so you skip `GetIDsOfNames`; the name is bound to an ID at compilation. None of this finds a function's *address*.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that compile-time linking to dynamic libraries would increase EXE size ? I believe you are mislead by somewhat poor choice of terms, used in windows programming from far ago. Let us better use relative terms "early binding" and "late binding" instead for the choice who should search for procedure names, compiler/loader or programmer's custom code.

Using early binding (aka **static linking against *dynamic* library**) your EXE contains the values (in a special tables):

- DLL1 Name:

  - - procedure "aaaaa" into the variable $1234
  - - procedure "bbbbb" into the variable $5678

.

- DLL2 Name:

  - - procedure "ccccc" into the variable $4567

...et cetera.

---

Now, when you turn this into runtime loading (**dynamic linking against *dynamic* libraries**) it would look like

```
   VarH1 := SafeLoatLibrary(DLL1 Name);
   if Error-Loading-DLL then do-error-handling;

   Var1234 := GetProcAfdress(VarH1, "aaaaa");
   if Error-Searching-For-Function then do-error-handling;

   Var5678 := GetProcAfdress(VarH1, "bbbbb");
   if Error-Searching-For-Function then do-error-handling;
```

et cetera.

Obviously in the latter case your EXE contains all those values like in the 1st case, but more so - it contains a lot of code to deal with those values, that was just absent before.

So, while EXE size difference is not really large for today memory sizes, it is still in favor of early binding (static compilation against dynamic library).

Then what are the benefits for late binding? For example you can load different DLLs from different paths, determined in runtime by configuration - the flexibility and avoiding of DLL Hell (funny, concept of avoiding DLL Hell is against concept of volume saving). You can make your application work with limited functionality, if DLL load failed while statically binded EXE would just not load - graceful degradation concept. And at least you may give user  much better, full of semantics, error messages than Windows could ever do.

---

And the last word, where you got that concept of EXE size from. I believe you mistaken it from talks about - attention! - **static linking against *static* libraries**. That is when OBJ/LIB/DCU files are not the part of distribution, but are just temporary code containers, that ultimately takes its place inside the monolythic EXE. Then yes - then your EXE has all those libraries insideitself and thus grows larger. However this case have nothing about *dynamic* libraries - DLLs.

The wording chosen once ago overuses static/dynamic terms in two closely related topics: how the library is loaded (compile-time vs runtime) and how functions inside the library are located (or bound. By developer's custom codeing ro by some OS-provided or compiler-provided toolset way before 1st line of your sources started execution).

Due to that ambiguity those close but different concepts start overlapping and sometimes this leads to a total confusion.

---

Now, what more static linking may give you in modern Windows versions. That is [WinSxS folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly) Novadays Windows tends to keep multiple versions of each system DLL and your program may ask for the specific version of it (while in *System32* folder there would be the most recent version that your program may be not get used to. Then you can make a special MANIFEST resource and compile it into EXE asking windows to load not DLLs not be name, but by name+version instead. You can replicaty that functionality with dynamic loading as well, but using Windows-provided toolset it is much easier.

Now you can decide which of those options do or do not have importance for your particular case and make somewhat better informed choice.

HTH.

Comment: There's no such thing as static linking against dynamic libraries. Dynamic libraries are dynamic, not static. Dynamic linking uses dynamic libraries, and static linking uses static libraries. You're confusing load-time dynamic linking with run-time dynamic linking. They're both dynamic.

Comment: @RobKennedy technically you're correct. But the term was used in early days, despite begin incorrect and ambiguous. That is providing for TS'es "when linking against Microsoft Windows dll files located in System32... follow the static linking approach" question. I try to be verbose, even if not theoretically correct and demonstrate how the confusion arose.