# how to use 3rd party library on android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, loadlibrary

I have hard time fnding out how to load and use compiled .so library in firemonkey application. I've managed to setup project in a way that it compiles and library is bundled in apk but can't load it when application starts. Is system.LoadLibrary() enough or do I need some java wrapper for the lib?

edit: my code looks like this now, still can't get past library loading stage.
TPath.GetLibraryPath returns correct path to where library is located ( I checked with adb pull)

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    LIBNAME = 'sunvox.dll';
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    LIBNAME = 'libsunvox.so';
{$ENDIF}

function sv_load_dll:integer;
var libPath:system.string;
begin
  g_sv_dll:= 0 ;
  libPath:=TPath.Combine(tpath.GetLibraryPath,libname);
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  g_sv_dll:=dlopen(MarshaledAString(libPath), RTLD_LAZY);
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  g_sv_dll := LoadLibrary(MarshaledString(libPath));
  {$ENDIF}
  result:=g_sv_dll;
  if( g_sv_dll = 0 )then exit;

  sv_audio_callback:=tsv_audio_callback(import('sv_audio_callback' ));
 ...
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show the a cut down version of what you currently have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can statically link to an exported function of the .so file using Delphi's standard `external` syntax on the function declaration, specifying the .so file as the external library.

Or you can dynamically load the .so into memory yourself using the `dlopen()` function, retrieve a pointer to the exported function using the `dlsym()` function, and release the library from memory using the `dlclose()` function.  These are the equivilents of `LoadLibrary()`, `GetProcAddress()` and `FreeLibrary()` on Windows.

See this discussion for an example:

[Difficulties with calling an Android NDK function from directly Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036994/)

Comment: ok, thanks that's good news. is there a way to set location to which library will be deployed (or obtain path at runtime) so application can find it? in example fixed path is used which is device specific

Comment: @laggyluk: [Standard RTL path locations across the supported target platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)